# Problem sending email to new user created with old email address

Tags: exchange, outlook

I removed one email address in the Exchange Server and created another one with the same address. Now I can not send messages to that address as it says no user exists, but I can see the new user in management console.  I can't connect to server using this email..... I'm very new in Exchange Server and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a cached entry on the Outlook client pointing to the old address.  Reload your OAB and delete the old email address from the NK2 file cache (Open a new message, start to type in the address, when the drop down appears with the address, hit Delete).  Then try to send it again.

Comment: +1, it's most likely cached info. Also, Exchange's OAB can be out of date as well depending on your update policies. Wait a couple hours and try again if it doesn't work the first time.